# haproxy-ingress not doing health check on TCP service

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I have haproxy-ingress set up on my kubernetes cluster.  It is working fine, I needed to set up memcached, deployed it and configured my haproxy-ingress with tcp-services-configmap and my configmap is as follows for the TCP services:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: haproxy-ingress-tcp
  namespace: ingress-controller
data:
  "11211": "default/memcached:11211"`

Everything works and I can access memcached on port 11211, when I log onto the stats page for haproxy-ingress, I can see the load balancing working for the 3 memcached instances but they are grey "not checked" in the haproxy stat page (I would expect them to be green (checked)).  Is there anyway to have haproxy-ingress do a status check on TCP ports?

Comment: This feature was just added to v0.10, give v0.10-beta.1 a chance. [doc](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/command-line/#tcp-services-configmap)

Comment: I upgraded to v0.10-beta1 and it is working now.  Talk about great timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `v0.10-beta.1` the tcp-service has a new positional config option which allows you to configure the time between tcp health checks. The default value is `2s` if not declared.

From the [doc](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/command-line/#tcp-services-configmap):

> `<check-interval>`, added in `v0.10`, optional and defaults to `2s`, configures a TCP check interval. Declare `-` (one single dash) as the time to disable it. Valid time is a number and a mandatory suffix: `us`, `ms`, `s`, `m`, `h` or `d`.